Validation of custom query path variables in spring boot
I am trying to validate two custom query path variables in this custom query:
@Slf4j
@AllArgsConstructor
@RestController
@Validated
@RequestMapping("api/standing_orders")
public class StandingOrderController {
...
@GetMapping("/by_validity_date_from_to")
    public ResponseEntity<List<StandingOrderResponseDTO>> getByValidFromBetween(
            @StartDateBeforeEndDate @RequestParam LocalDate startDate, @StartDateBeforeEndDate @RequestParam LocalDate endDate) {
        log.info("Received request to find standing order valid from {} to {}", startDate, endDate);
        List<StandingOrderResponseDTO> orders = standingOrderService.findByValidFromBetween(startDate, endDate);
        log.info(orders.toString());
        return ResponseEntity.ok(orders);
    }

This custom query is for showing the standing orders between two dates. I want to make sure that the starting date is not later than the ending date, so I am making a ConstraintValidator for it:
package sk.softec.akademia.demo.validation;

import jakarta.validation.Constraint;
import jakarta.validation.Payload;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target({ ElementType.PARAMETER })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = StartDateBeforeEndDateValidator.class)
public @interface StartDateBeforeEndDate {
    String message() default "Start date cannot be later than end date";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}

and
package sk.softec.akademia.demo.validation;

import jakarta.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import jakarta.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;
import sk.softec.akademia.demo.DTO.StandingOrderRequestDTO;

import java.time.LocalDate;

public class StartDateBeforeEndDateValidator implements ConstraintValidator<StartDateBeforeEndDate, Object[]> {
    @Override
    public void initialize(StartDateBeforeEndDate value) {}

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Object[] values, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (values == null || values.length < 2 || !(values[0] instanceof LocalDate) || !(values[1] instanceof LocalDate)) {
            return true;
        }
        LocalDate startDate = (LocalDate) values[0];
        LocalDate endDate = (LocalDate) values[1];
        return startDate == null || endDate == null || !startDate.isAfter(endDate);
    }

Unfortunately, it doesn't work as intented, because I get this:
No validator could be found for constraint ...demo.validation.StartDateBeforeEndDate' validating type 'java.time.LocalDate'. Check configuration for 'getByValidFromBetween.startDate'
I don't want to make a new DTO for it, so my question is, is it actually possible to validate two request parameters together?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Have a look at the class-Validator in https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator

Don't. Instead create a DTO to bind the variables, and apply the validator to the DTO instead of the controller. Ditch the @Validated from the controller as you don't need it then.

Haven't tried it, but you can try to pass additional to your parameters list Spring WebRequest as described here

Than apply StartDateBeforeEndDateValidator on WebRequest. With
WebRequest.getParameter you will have access to passed parameters as String
public class StartDateBeforeEndDateValidator implements ConstraintValidator<StartDateBeforeEndDate, WebRequest> {
    @Override
    public void initialize(StartDateBeforeEndDate value) {}

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(WebRequest request, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
  
        LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.parse(request.getParameter("startDate");
        LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.parse(request.getParameter("endDate"); //null check. parse check to be added
        return startDate == null || endDate == null || !startDate.isAfter(endDate);
    }

controller
    @GetMapping("/by_validity_date_from_to")
    public ResponseEntity<List<StandingOrderResponseDTO>> getByValidFromBetween(
             @RequestParam LocalDate startDate, @RequestParam LocalDate endDate, @StartDateBeforeEndDate WebRequest request ) {
        log.info("Received request to find standing order valid from {} to {}", startDate, endDate);
        List<StandingOrderResponseDTO> orders = standingOrderService.findByValidFromBetween(startDate, endDate);
        log.info(orders.toString());
        return ResponseEntity.ok(orders);
    }


Shouldn't your validator for this case implement ConstraintValidator<StartDateBeforeEndDate, LocalDate>? Or even Object?
Spring will try to look for a validator that matches LocalDate, but you have one defined for an array of objects, although the validator is applied once for each LocalDate parameter (so two validators).
I think your implementation would have worked if you had something like:
public ResponseEntity<List<StandingOrderResponseDTO>> getByValidFromBetween(
            @StartDateBeforeEndDate @RequestParam Object[] startDate) {
        ...
}

But don't do it like this. Better make your custom validator implement ConstraintValidator<StartDateBeforeEndDate, LocalDate> and update its handling logic.
(Or create your own DTO and add a validator over it)

You must be getting error-

No validator could be found for constraint LocalDate.

as you have written constraint for objects[] array and in api you are adding it to LocalDate object for validation.
replace your api method like this
public ResponseEntity<> getByValidFromBetween(
        @StartDateBeforeEndDate
        @RequestParam
        LocalDate[] dates
)

hope it helps!
Thanks.
